# Trying to create a custom dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom dialog.  I'm getting 2 compile errors, and don't really understand why.

1. The Method SetOnClickListner in the type view is not applicable for the arguments new OnClikLiatner
   code :
2. The methed on click view in type new OnClickListener must override supertype

Code giving the errors:

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // error message 1 here
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) { // error message 2 here
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

All the code

```
 void StartGame()
       {
        // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( cGlobals.MainHome );
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_play);
                    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            //      ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();


       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define this at the top

```
final Context context = this;
```

then change

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // error message 1 hear
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) { // error message 2 hear
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

to this:

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();   
                }
            });
```

and this

```
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( cGlobals.MainHome );
```

to

```
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, could you explain the fix?

Comment: welcome, the first change as you can see, you were missing the view. You should declare where do you want the clicks listener? so we wanted it in the view.

Comment: Second is I'm not sure what is yours cGlobals.MainHome, but when you are creating something new, you should always create it in current activity which we replaced with context(this)